# How to create blog listing with categories using structure?

Tags: ee2, templates, structure

I am using structure for the pages of a site and am curious as to how the "Listings" type is supposed to work. It seems to allow me to provide a listing template and to specify the template that is used for each individual article.

However, there doesn't appear to be a way to have categories and archives.

How can this be achieved or can Structure not be used to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need an additional addon like [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie), which allows the system to ignore certain segments.

There's a [reasonably complete walkthrough](http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/categories_sorting_and_displaying/) in the Structure documentation and [this blog post on 3 Roads Media](http://www.3roadsmedia.com/blog/expressionengine-with-structure-and-categories/) also covers the same idea.

Comment: Awesome! nice and straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Freebie is good, but [Zoo Triggers](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-triggers) is better, and a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: +1 Install it and forget it.

Comment: $15 is a steal for that if it just works

Answer (score 1):

While you can use Structure to manage blog entries, you don't have to.

I have a number of blogs on Structure-enabled sites where the blog entries themselves are not managed through Structure, only the blog's main page is.

The blog's main page is managed as a page, and the blog entries are set as a listing under it.  Creating and editing blog entries is handled through EE.

This allows you to use categories and tags without Structure interfering, and without the need for other plug-ins.  Although those plug-ins are top-notch.

Again, a number of ways to skin that cat with EE.